# Will Allah forgive me for this major sin?

Tags: halal-haram, sin, ramadan, doubts

I broke the fast in Ramadan before Maghrib back then the last time I did it was 2020 and I was stupid back then yes I did I it on purpose and I didn’t know there would be a punishment. Back then I didn’t follow my religion but now I realized my mistake I asked by dad for advice and he said just repent but some people say to fast for 60 consecutive days but I’ve done it more than once and I’m worried I would have to fast for a long time.

Comment: What was your age last year when you broke the fast? Were you of the age at which fast is obligatory?

Comment: Yes I was and I’m unhappy about it

Comment: I guess you are/were aware of the ruling for kafarah too? In that case you have no excuse.

Comment: No I did it know there was a kafarah but do I just fast the days I missed right? And do the days of fasting in Ramadan count or does it have to be outside Ramadan.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you repent with a sincere heart then God is indeed Most Forgiving and Most Merciful.

*O you who have believed, repent to God with sincere repentance. Perhaps your Lord will remove from you your misdeeds and admit you into gardens beneath which rivers flow [on] the Day when God will not disgrace the Prophet and those who believed with him. Their light will proceed before them and on their right; they will say, "Our Lord, perfect for us our light and forgive us. Indeed, You are over all things competent."*

-Quran 66:8

You must always stay in remembrance of God, doing upon the will of God, and always staying in humble submission to God.

*Therefore remember Me, I will remember you, and be thankful to Me, and do not be ungrateful to Me.*

-Quran 2:157

The Prophet Muhammad said: *“Whoever says: ‘Glory is to God, and with His Praise (Subḥān Allāh, wa biḥamdih)’ a hundred times, his sins are forgiven, even if they were like the foam of the sea.”*

-Jami` at-Tirmidhi 3466

The Prophet Muhammad said:

*“Whoever says: ‘Laa ilaaha ill-Allaah wahdahu laa shareeka lah, lahu’l-mulk wa lahu’l-hamd wa huwa ‘ala kulli shay’in qadeer (There is no god but Allah alone with no partner or associate, His is the dominion, to Him be praise and He has power over all things)’ one hundred times in a day, it will be the equivalent of his freeing ten slaves, and one hundred good deeds will be recorded for him, and one hundred bad deeds will be erased for him, and it will be a protection for him against the shaytaan all that day until evening comes, and no one will do anything better than what he has done except one who does more than that.”*

-Sahih al-Bukhari 3293 and Sahih Muslim 2691

The Prophet Muhammad said:

*“Whoever says in the morning and in the evening: ‘Subhaan Allaah wa bi hamdihi (Glory and praise be to Allah)’ one hundred times, no one will come on the Day of Resurrection with anything better than what he has done, except one who said something like what he said, or more than that.”*

-Sahih Muslim 2692

Therefore, if you do upon all that, repent with a sincere repentance, and be in humble submission to God, then indeed you will be upon the right path, and at the end, everything is in accordance to the will of God.

Comment: None of what you claim has a weight against Allah's orders in the verses 2:183-187 which make clear that what he commited is a major sin and he needs to perform a kafarah beside repentance.

Comment: You are right, @ياsr, he needs to make up for the missed fasts, and along with that, he also needs to repent to Allah with a sincere repentance. Indeed Allah is Ever Forgiving and Ever Merciful.